# ADC with DMA not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I am using dsPIC33EP512MU810 to simultaneous sample 4 signals from a mic and display the samples on the on-board tft screen on the EasyPIC Fusion v7 development board.

I was successful in acheiving my goal of doing this task without DMA, but now have come to a dead end when using DMA.

Furthermore, I am using the in-built TFT display library available in MikroC for dsPIC compiler. It's [Link](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/tft_library.htm).

The screen is showing 0 for all four channels (no data is being read from the ADC). I have gone through the connections and datasheets many times but can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please go through my code to find the error?

```
// TFT module connections
char TFT_DataPort at LATE;
sbit TFT_RST at LATD7_bit;
sbit TFT_BLED at LATD2_bit;
sbit TFT_RS at LATD9_bit;
sbit TFT_CS at LATD10_bit;
sbit TFT_RD at LATD5_bit;
sbit TFT_WR at LATD4_bit;
char TFT_DataPort_Direction at TRISE;
sbit TFT_RST_Direction at TRISD7_bit;
sbit TFT_BLED_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit TFT_RS_Direction at TRISD9_bit;
sbit TFT_CS_Direction at TRISD10_bit;
sbit TFT_RD_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit TFT_WR_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
// End TFT module connections

void init_MCU();
void init_LCD();
void load_background();
void draw_pulse();
void refresh_axis();
void readAdc(adcResults);
void int_ADC();
void init_DMA();
void DMA5Interrupt();

int ch_incr[4] = {60, 120, 180, 240};

int New_X[4], New_Y[4], Adc_Values[4];
int Curr_X[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int Curr_Y[4] = {60, 120, 180, 240};
int i = 0, j = 0, k;
int Curr_Val[4] = {0}, Scaled_Val[4];
int ADCValues[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

struct adcResults {
  unsigned int Adc1Ch0[8];
  unsigned int Adc1Ch1[8];
  unsigned int Adc1Ch2[8];
  unsigned int Adc1Ch3[8];
}BufferA, BufferB;

typedef struct adcResults ADCResults;
ADCResults *ptr;


void main() {
  init_MCU();
  init_LCD();
  int_ADC();
  init_DMA();
  load_background();

  while(1) {
    draw_pulse();
  }
}

void init_MCU() {
  // PLL settings
  CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;      // PLLPRE<4:0> = 0  ->  N1 = 2    8MHz / 2 =   4MHz
                              // (must be within 0.8 MHz to 8 MHz range)
  PLLFBD =   38;              // PLLDIV<8:0> = 48 ->  M = 40    4MHz * 40 = 160MHz
                              // (must be within 100 MHz to 200 MHz range)
  CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;     // PLLPOST<1:0> = 0 ->  N2 = 2    160MHz / 2 = 80MHz
                              // (must be within 12.5 MHz to 80 MHz range)

  ANSELD = 0xFF;          // Set All pins as digital
  ANSELE = 0xFF;
  ANSELC = 0xFF;
}

void init_LCD() {
  TFT_BLED_Direction = 0;
  TFT_Set_Default_Mode();
  TFT_Init_ILI9341_8bit(320, 240);
  TFT_BLED = 1;
}
void load_background() {
  // Enable gradient from black to white color, left-right orientation
  TFT_Set_Brush(1, CL_BLACK, 1, TOP_TO_Bottom, CL_BLACK, CL_WHITE);
  TFT_Fill_Screen(CL_BLACK);
  TFT_Set_Brush(0, 0, 1, LEFT_TO_RIGHT, CL_BLACK, CL_WHITE);
  TFT_Set_Pen(CL_GRAY, 1);
  TFT_H_Line(10, 310, 60);                       //x-start, x-stop, y-axis
  TFT_H_Line(10, 310, 120);                       //x-start, x-stop, y-axis
  TFT_H_Line(10, 310, 180);                       //x-start, x-stop, y-axis
  TFT_H_Line(10, 310, 240);                       //x-start, x-stop, y-axis
}

void draw_pulse() {

  for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
    Scaled_Val[k] = ch_incr[k] - ((ceil(Curr_Val[k])/1023)* 60);
  }

  for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
    New_X[k] = i;
    New_Y[k] = Scaled_Val[k];
  }

  if(i < 318) {
  TFT_Set_PEN(CL_BLACK, 1);
  TFT_V_Line(0,240,i+1);
  TFT_Set_PEN(CL_RED, 1);
  TFT_V_Line(0,240,i+2);
  }
  else if(i == 319){
  TFT_Set_PEN(CL_BLACK, 2);
  TFT_V_Line(0,240,i+1);
  }


  TFT_Set_Pen(CL_RED, 2);
  TFT_Line(Curr_X[0], Curr_Y[0], New_X[0], New_Y[0]);
  TFT_Set_Pen(CL_BLUE, 2);
  TFT_Line(Curr_X[1], Curr_Y[1], New_X[1], New_Y[1]);
  TFT_Set_Pen(CL_GREEN, 2);
  TFT_Line(Curr_X[2], Curr_Y[2], New_X[2], New_Y[2]);
  TFT_Set_Pen(CL_YELLOW, 2);
  TFT_Line(Curr_X[3], Curr_Y[3], New_X[3], New_Y[3]);

  for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
    Curr_Y[k] = New_Y[k];
    Curr_X[k] = New_X[k];
    if(Curr_X[k] == 320) {
      Curr_X[k] = 0;
    }
  }

  if(i == 320) {
   i = 0;
  TFT_Set_PEN(CL_BLACK, 1);
  TFT_V_Line(0,240,i);
  }
  i++;
}

void int_ADC() {
  /* Initialize and enable ADC module */
     AD1CON1 = 0x004C;               // Enable simultaneous sampling and auto-sample
     AD1CON2 = 0x0300;               // Sample 4 channels
     AD1CON3 = 0x003F;
     AD1CON4 = 0x0100;
     AD1CSSH = 0x0000;
     AD1CSSL = 0x0000;
     AD1CHS0bits.CH0SA = 3;          // Select AN3 for CH0 +ve input
     AD1CHS0bits.CH0NA = 0;          // Select Vref- for CH0 -ve input
     AD1CHS123bits.CH123SA = 0;      // Select AN0 for CH1 +ve input
                                     // Select AN1 for CH2 +ve input
                                     // Select AN2 for CH3 +ve input
     AD1CHS123bits.CH123NA = 0;
                                     // Select Vref- for CH1/CH2/CH3 -ve inputs

     //Set up Timer3 to trigger ADC1 conversions:
     TMR3 = 0x0000;
     PR3 = 4999; // Trigger ADC1 every 125usec
     IFS0bits.T3IF = 0; // Clear Timer3 interrupt
     IEC0bits.T3IE = 0; // Disable Timer3 interrupt
     T3CONbits.TON = 1; //Start Timer3

     //Set up ADC1 for DMA operation:
     AD1CON1bits.ADDMABM = 0; // DMA buffers are built in scatter/
     AD1CON2bits.SMPI = 3; // 4 ADC buffers
     AD1CON4bits.DMABL = 3; // Each buffer contains 8 words
     IFS0bits.AD1IF = 0; // Clear the A/D interrupt flag
     IEC0bits.AD1IE = 0; // Do Not Enable A/D interrupt
     AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1; // Turn on the A/D converter

}

void readAdc(ADCResults *p)
{
  Curr_Val[0] = p->Adc1Ch0; // Read the AN0 conversion result
  Curr_Val[1] = p->Adc1Ch1; // Read the AN1 conversion result
  Curr_Val[2] = p->Adc1Ch2; // Read the AN2 conversion result
  Curr_Val[3] = p->Adc1Ch3; // Read the AN3 conversion result
}

void init_DMA(void)
{
  //Set up DMA Channel 5 for Peripheral Indirect Addressing:

  DMA5CONbits.AMODE = 2; // Configure DMA for Peripheral indirect mode
  DMA5CONbits.MODE = 2; // Configure DMA for Continuous Ping-Pong mode
  DMA5PAD = (volatile unsigned int)&ADC1BUF0; // Point DMA to ADC1BUF0
  DMA5CNT = 31; // 32 DMA request (4 buffers, each with 8 words)
  DMA5REQ = 13; // Select ADC1 as DMA Request source
  DMA5STAH = 0x0000;
  DMA5STAL = 0x0000;
  DMA5STAH = 0x0000;
  DMA5STAL = 0x1000;
  IFS3bits.DMA5IF = 0; //Clear the DMA interrupt flag bit
  IEC3bits.DMA5IE = 1; //Set the DMA interrupt enable bit
  DMA5CONbits.CHEN=1; // Enable DMA
}

//Set up DMA Channel 5 Interrupt Handler:
unsigned int DmaBuffer = 0;
void DMA5Interrupt()
{
  // Switch between Primary and Secondary Ping-Pong buffers
  if(DmaBuffer == 0) {
    ptr = &BufferA;
    readADC(ptr);
  }
  else {
    ptr = &BufferB;
    readADC(ptr);
  }
  DmaBuffer = ~DmaBuffer;
  IFS3bits.DMA5IF = 0; //Clear the DMA5 Interrupt Flag
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Changed ADC1CON4 = 0x0100;

It did enable the dma, but now the lcd screen keeps on blinking and is unable to display anything. The reason I think is the constant interrupts occurring and keeping the cpu occupied.

I am using 8MHz crystal and internal PLL circuitory to generate a 80Mhz clock.

Can someone guide me how I should select Timer3 timeout, dma buffer size and how do I calculate the maximum ammount of sample rate I can work with, without overloading the MCU?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You've just dumped a whole design in your question and haven't explained your approach. To get the best answer, you should provide some explanation of your intention and what debugging results you have.

Comment: I have added additional details for my work and tried my best to explain my approach. I will answer any follow up questions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the INitADC fuction, you do not enable the DMA in control register 4.

Try

```
AD1CON4bits.ADDMAEN = 1;
```

-OR-

```
AD1CON4 = 0x0100;
```

See page 424 dsPIC33EP512MU810 userguide / ref manual.

Comment: Thank you it really was a mistake. But this has lead to another major problem. The LCD screen keeps on turning on and off and cannot display anything at all. I think it is because of constant interrupts occuring and continously occupying the cpu. Can you please guide me how I should select Timer3 timeout and BUFFER size for the DMA?

Comment: @MohsinAnees if this is a modification of your question then you should edit your above question, otherwise (more likely, in this case) you should start a new question detailing your new issues.